# PHP regex for url validation, filter_var is too permisive

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

First lets define a "URL" according to my requirements.

The only protocols optionally allowed are `http://` and `https://`

then a mandatory domain name like `stackoverflow.com`

then optionally the rest of url components (`path`, `query`, `hash`, ...)

For reference a list of valid and invalid url's according to my requirements

## VALID

- stackoverflow.com
- stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
- http://www.amazon.com/Computers-Internet-Books/b/ref=bhp_bb0309A_comint2?ie=UTF8&node=5&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=browse&pf_rd_r=0AH7GM29WF81Q72VPFDH&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1273387142&pf_rd_i=283155
- amazon.com/Computers-Internet-Books/b/ref=bhp_bb0309A_comint2?ie=UTF8&node=5&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=browse&pf_rd_r=0AH7GM29WF81Q72VPFDH&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=1273387142&pf_rd_i=283155
- http://test-site.com (filter_var reject this!!! I have domain names with dashes )

## INVALID

- http://www (php filter_var allow this, yes i know is a `valid` url)
- google
- http://www..des (php filter_var allow this)
- Any url with not allowed characters in the domain name

For completeness here is my php version: `5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2`

Comment: You have domain names under a TLD with dashes? Show me.

Comment: I hope you do know that now there are [internationalized domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) which can make URL-validating regexes pretty messy.

Comment: Also, there are lots of things "valid" URLs can contain and are not specified in your question. For the complete spec see this: http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

Comment: @Pekka http://www.expert-sex-change.com used to redirect to stackoverflow.com (now expired)

Comment: @Null aarrgh, of course, I mixed it up with underscores `_`. I own a number of domains with dashes myself. Time for me to call it a day! I don't understand how filter_var can reject this, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a starting point** you can use this one, **it's for JS**, but it's easy to convert it to work for PHP `preg_match`.

```
/^(https?\://)?(www\.)?([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]|(\-[a-z0-9]))*\.)+[a-z]+$/i
```

For PHP should work this one:

```
$reg = '@^(https?\://)?(www\.)?([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]|(\-[a-z0-9]))*\.)+[a-z]+$@i';
```

**This regexp anyway validates only the domain part**, but you can work on this or split the url at the 1st slash `'/'` (after `"://"`) and validate separately the domain part and the rest.

BTW: It would validate also `"http://www.domain.com.com"` but this is not an error because a subdomain url could be like: `"http://www.subdomain.domain.com"` and it's valid! And **there is almost no way (or at least no operatively easy way) to validate for proper domain tld with a regex** because you would have to write inline into your regex all possible domain tlds ONE BY ONE like this:

```
/^(https?\://)?(www\.)?([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9]|(\-[a-z0-9]))*\.)+(com|it|net|uk|de)$/i
```

(this last one for instance would validate only domain ending with .com/.net/.de/.it/.co.uk). **New tlds always come out**, so you would have to adjust you regex everytimne a new tld comes out, that's a pain in the neck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to break up the address into its components. While it's explicitly not built to validate a URL, analyzing the resulting components and matching them against your requirements would at least be a start.

Answer (score 0):

It may vary but in most of the cases you don't really need to check the validity of any URL.

If it's a vital information and you trust your user enough to let him give it through a URL, you can trust him enough to give a valid URL.

If it isn't a vital information, then you just have to check for XSS attempts and display the URL that the user wanted.

You can add manually a "http://" if you don't detect one to avoid navigation problems.

---

I know, I don't give you an alternative as a solution, but maybe the best way to solve performance & validity problems is just to avoid unnecessary checks.