# How to make sure sure that a string contains a valid/well formed url?

Tags: php, validation, url

How to make sure that a string contains a valid/well formed url?

I need be sure the url in the string is well formed.

It must contain `http://` or `https://`

and `.com` or `.org` or `.net` or `any other valid extension`

I tried some of the answers found here in SO but all are accepting "www.google.com" as valid.

In my case the valid url needs to be `http://`www.google.com or `https://`www.google.com.

The `www.` part is not an obligation, since some urls dont use it.

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_URL is not acceptible because "localhost" is a valid url on it, but cant be on my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the answer here:
[PHP regex for url validation, filter_var is too permisive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653884/php-regex-for-url-validation-filter-var-is-too-permisive)

`filter_var()` could be just fine for you, but if you need something more powerful, you'll have to use regex.

Additionally with the code from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), you can sub-in any regex that suits your needs:

```
<?php 
    $regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME 
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass 
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})"; // Host or IP 
    $regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port 
    $regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path 
    $regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query 
    $regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor 
?> 

Then, the correct way to check against the regex list as follows: 

<?php 
       if(preg_match("/^$regex$/", $url)) 
       { 
               return true; 
       } 
?>
```

Comment: yeah, but i dont have sufficient knowledge to make a regex to deal with my needs.

Comment: but it's right in the answer at the link :)

Comment: yesh but on this expression in the link the http part is optional, i need that part.

Comment: thanks, i changed `"((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME` to `"(https?|ftp)\:\/\/"; // SCHEME` to make it mandatory. Looks like its fine now.

Answer (score 1):

YOU can do this by using php `filter_var` function

```
$valid=filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)

if($valid){
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a curl solution:

```
function url_exists($url) {
    if (!$fp = curl_init($url)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

and there's a fopen solution (if you don't have

```
function url_exists($url) {
    $fp = @fopen('http://example.com', 'r'); // @suppresses all error messages
    if ($fp) {
        // connection was made to server at domain example.com
        fclose($fp);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)` can be first used to make sure you are dealing with a valid URL.

Then you have more conditions that can be tested by assuming the URL is indeed valid with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$res = parse_url($url);
return ($res['scheme'] == 'http' || $ret['scheme'] == 'https') && $res['host'] != 'localhost');
```

Comment: Can you pls explain me how to use it?

Comment: @LucasMatos I believe my example is quite clear. Is there something you do not understand ?